# Query all objects by date | Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I would like to add an URL like 'reports/'int:year'/month/'int:month'' and list all the reports that I have for that month of that year

Currently, my view.py is like that :

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

class ReportGroupData(ListAPIView):
    queryset=Report.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('month', 'count').order_by('-month')
    serializer_class = ReportGroupMonthSerializer
```

In Django I did it like this :

urls.py :

```
path('reports/<int:year>/month/<int:month>', ReportMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'),
         name='report_archive_month'),
```

Views.py :

```
class ReportMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/reports_month.html'
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    date_field = "date"
    allow_future = True
    paginate_by = 7
```

What are the steps to have something similar in DRF?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the same ViewSet with 2 different URLs. The existing one can treat the Year & Month as optional, and if present, filter the queryset by the same.

Comment: Ok, how can I add this condition? 
should I override the present ViewSet get request and add the condition in there? and depending on the presence those two arguments return the normal query set or the filter one?

Comment: I found this : 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters
Were you talking about this? 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @shad0w_wa1k3r comment, what I did is , i Overided the current Viewset and following DRF 'filtering-against-query-parameters' example i ended up doing this :

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Report.objects.all()
        date = self.request.query_params.get('date', None)
        if date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date=date)
        return queryset
```

It works, I'll tweak it a bit, but I guess on front-end, I'll just need to do an ajax request with the date parameter to get the desired reports.